# Selectize js push chosen option to the top of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I've chosen selectize.js as it fits my needs.
One thing I can't force it to do is to move the chosen option to the top of the list.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArekKDev/phkuz4Lb/3/) version

```js
    const selectizeInit = (() => {

        "use strict";

        const s = {
            selectBasic: "selectize-basic"
        };

        // console.log('s', s)

        const initialize = () => {
            const selectFields = document.querySelectorAll('.selectize-basic');

            selectFields && selectFields.forEach( select => {

                $(select).selectize({

                    // hideSelected: true,
                    create: false,
                    maxItems: 1,
                    valueField: 'country',
                    labelField: 'pref',
                    searchField: ['country', 'pref', 'code'],
                    sortField: [{
                        field: 'priority',
                        direction: 'asc'
                    },{
                        field: 'country',
                        direction: 'asc'
                    }],
                    highlight: true,
                    placeholder: 'Search',
                    openOnFocus: true,
                    options: countryCodes,
                    items: ['Bhutan'],
                    render: {
                        item: function(item, escape) {
                            return `
                                <div class="select-item">
                                <span>${escape(item.pref)}</span>
                                </div>
                            `;
                        },
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                            return `
                                <div class="select-item">
                                    <span class="select-item__country">${escape(item.pref)}</span>
                                    <span class="select-item__prefix">${escape(item.country)}</span>
                                </div>
                            `;
                        }
                    },
                    onChange: function(country_name) {
                        if (this.options) {
                            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.options)) {
                                this.options[key].priority = 1;
                            }
                            this.options[country_name].priority = 0;
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        };

        const countryCodes = [
            {
                "country": "Afghanistan",
                "pref": "+93",
                "code": "AF",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Aland Islands",
                "pref": "+358",
                "code": "AX",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Albania",
                "pref": "+355",
                "code": "AL",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Algeria",
                "pref": "+213",
                "code": "DZ",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "AmericanSamoa",
                "pref": "+1684",
                "code": "AS",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Andorra",
                "pref": "+376",
                "code": "AD",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Angola",
                "pref": "+244",
                "code": "AO",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Anguilla",
                "pref": "+1264",
                "code": "AI",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Antarctica",
                "pref": "+672",
                "code": "AQ",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
                "pref": "+1268",
                "code": "AG",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Argentina",
                "pref": "+54",
                "code": "AR",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Armenia",
                "pref": "+374",
                "code": "AM",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Aruba",
                "pref": "+297",
                "code": "AW",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Australia",
                "pref": "+61",
                "code": "AU",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Austria",
                "pref": "+43",
                "code": "AT",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Azerbaijan",
                "pref": "+994",
                "code": "AZ",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Bahamas",
                "pref": "+1242",
                "code": "BS",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Bahrain",
                "pref": "+973",
                "code": "BH",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Bangladesh",
                "pref": "+880",
                "code": "BD",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Barbados",
                "pref": "+1246",
                "code": "BB",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Belarus",
                "pref": "+375",
                "code": "BY",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Belgium",
                "pref": "+32",
                "code": "BE",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Belize",
                "pref": "+501",
                "code": "BZ",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Benin",
                "pref": "+229",
                "code": "BJ",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "country": "Bermuda",
                "pref": "+1441",
                "code": "BM",
                "priority": 1
            }
        ];

        const init = () => {
            initialize();
        };

        return {
            init
        };
    })();

    {
        selectizeInit.init();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.6/css/selectize.min.css" integrity="sha512-zSutnLmqtlWVx0A5NdW8YwshpUETPzJ6YBAvb+bkE0QbVKopS0ACPjE6QY6F9aFPSowfiho+hgeQh095FRPj5A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <label for="phone-prefix" class="form-label">Prefix</label>
    <select class="selectize-basic" name="phonePrefix" id="phone-prefix"></select>
  </div>
<script>
    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've done is - I added priority field to countryCodes and then on change I change priority for the chosen option.

Then filtering is set to display an option with highest priority as first one.

It all works fine the only problem is that the chosen option is displayed as the first one with delay, it doesn't appear at the top when it's chosen but just when other option is selected.

I think I tried all methods available for selectize but to no avail. I already checked with my colleagues but the also couldn't figure it out. So I'm trying here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the selectize object, and use it to update the option. Just updating the data does not inform selectize that something has changed. You need to call the API `updateOption` to inform the library about it.

You can use below code. I have made the changes in `onChange` method to update the option.

```
let selectizeObj = $(select).selectize({

    // hideSelected: true,
    create: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    valueField: 'country',
    labelField: 'pref',
    searchField: ['country', 'pref', 'code'],
    sortField: [{
        field: 'priority',
        direction: 'asc'
    },{
        field: 'country',
        direction: 'asc'
    }],
    highlight: true,
    placeholder: 'Search',
    openOnFocus: true,
    options: countryCodes,
    items: ['Bhutan'],
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
            return `
                <div class="select-item">
                <span>${escape(item.pref)}</span>
                </div>
            `;
        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return `
                <div class="select-item">
                    <span class="select-item__country">${escape(item.pref)}</span>
                    <span class="select-item__prefix">${escape(item.country)}</span>
                </div>
            `;
        }
    },
    onChange: function(country_name) {
        if (this.options) {
                // console.log(this.options);
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.options)) {
                this.options[key].priority = 1;
            }
            this.options[country_name].priority = 0;
            selectizeObj[0].selectize.updateOption(country_name, this.options[country_name]);
        }
        
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. It works exactly the way I needed.
There is one more thing I find difficult to do. 
I have a list of countries with phone prefixes. The library doesn't allow for duplicates which is the case for many countries with prefix "1" on my list. Do you know how to force it to accept duplicates?